# How are the laser printer CMYK colors mixed when printing

Tags: printer, colors, cmyk

I'm writing an application which should analyze a PDF page and tell based on the toner prices and other costs how much does this page cost.
The problem here is that I don't know how colors are mixed in the printer (using CMYK model).

Suppose I have one pixel filled with magenta, then I have the same pixel with the colour which is exactly half magenta and half yellow. Is a toner consumption same in both cases? Or there is twice as much toner used in the second case?

Is black toner used for anything else than grey? For example really dark blue?

I need to get page price, based on grey/colour percentage. I have typical manufacturers data (toner price, number of pages with certain toner coverage, that can be printed).

Comment: Portions of your question are likely to vary by printer manufacturer.  For the most accurate information, contact the tech support department at the major manufacturers.  You would need to do that anyway because toner costs and mileage vary (and the published pages per cartridge may be based on different testing methods).

Comment: @Hennes, why would you take a correctly spelled word, like "color", and purposely misspell it?  There are readers outside GB, you know.

Comment: Matter of habit. I went in to change one tag. Saw 'pdf' and capitalised it. I guess I automatically got to colour.